# How to show dropdown Animation for a list(RecyclerView) under Edittext?

Tags: android, drop-down-menu, android-animation, dropdown

I am trying to show drop-down list using recycler view under edit text.

Recycler view supposed to slide down from behind Edit-text but it gets visible before sliding down.[image: As you can see recycler view is sliding down from behind the edit text but it is also visible before the edit text][image: Recycler view is completely visible in the second picture as a drop-down list]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this, I hope this will help you.

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/green">

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/google_map_fragment"
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"/>


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <android.support.v7.widget.SearchView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="200dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="15dp">
        </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>


    </LinearLayout>


</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Done! Answer Accepted!